# jQuery EasyUI plugin instantiate programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I need to instantiate an easyUI propertygrid programmatically and attach it to a div. It should be easy but I am new to jQuery and EasyUI.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <table id="pg" class="easyui-propertygrid" style="width:300px">
  </table>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#pg').propertygrid({
   url:'path/to/json/file',
   showGroup:true,
   scrollbarSize:1
});
```

link to [demos](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=PropertyGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=)